# Dynamic Char Allocation

Tags: c++, char

I have a loop that brings me a buffer each time, I want to concatenate the buffers in a `char` array named `data` and then I want write this data into a file, but the problem is that I can't concatenate the `char` without seg-fault/core-dumped.

Here's the code (I also tried `new char[sizeof]` instead of `malloc`):

```
int size = getFrames() * 4;
char * buffer = (char *) malloc(size);

char * data;
char * tmp;

for (loops = 100; loops > 0; loops--) {
    buffer = getBuffer();

    tmp = (char *) malloc(sizeof(data));
    tmp = data;

    data = (char *) malloc(sizeof(tmp) + sizeof(buffer));
    data = strcat(tmp, buffer);
}

free(tmp);
free(data);
free(buffer);
```

Comment: Using malloc/free (or raw dynamic memory allocation with new/delete) in C++ is almost always a bad idea. Why are you doing it?

Comment: What do you think `tmp = data;` does? (Hint: the meaning of `=` is exactly the same on that line as it was on the previous line)

Comment: 'cos i don't want to use string and i can't see another way to do that, i also tried new char[sizeof] buf still doenst works e.e

Comment: What about simply using `std::string` (as you're asking for c++?) _"'cos i don't want to use string"_ any good reasoning for that?

Comment: "cos i don't want to use string" - why not? Your code is full of errors, the code for std::string  isn't.

Comment: is for audio capture, i don't think that string is faster than char

Comment: "i don't think that string is faster than char" - why don't you think that?

Comment: ok man, i know that my code is full of errors, but i don't need that, i need a solution, anyone can help me? nop, ok, thank you

Comment: `i don't think that string is faster than char` But you clearly don't know how to program in C++. How can you leap to a conclusion like that?

Comment: @Radagast _"i don't think that string is faster than char"_ where did you get this myth from? I just does what you try but in a right and bug free way.

Comment: The correct solution has been posted: use `std::string`

Comment: If what you are intending to do is write the incoming data to a file, then why not just do that and avoid having an ever expanding buffer. Why not just open the file and append the new data to it?

Comment: stick a few `cout`s (or `printf`s since your dead set on using c functions) in your code and see what `sizeof` is returning and compare the number of mallocs you do to the number of frees.

Comment: @Remy _"This code is ridiculous"_ Be nice ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not managing your buffers correctly, not even close.  In fact, there are a LOT of mistakes in your code. Every one of your `sizeof()` calls is wrong. You are leaking `buffer`, `tmp`, and `data` on every loop iteration. You are using `strcat()` incorrectly. And worse, you are processing *binary audio data* using *string functions*?  No wonder why your code is failing.

Try something more like this instead:

```
char* getBuffer(int *bufsize)
{
    ...
    *bufsize = ...; // <-- number of bytes being returned
    return ... ; // <-- malloc()'ed pointer to actual bytes
}

...

char *data = NULL;
int datasize = 0;
int allocsize = 0;

char *buffer;
int bufsize;

for (loops = 100; loops > 0; loops--) {
    buffer = getBuffer(&bufsize);

    if ((datasize + bufsize) > allocsize)
    {
        // round new size up to next 1K boundary
        int tmpsize = (datasize + bufsize + 1023) & ~1023;

        char *tmp = (char*) realloc(data, tmpsize);
        if (!tmp) {
            free(buffer);
            break;
        }

        data = tmp;
        allocsize = tmpsize;
    }

    memcpy(data + datasize, buffer, bufsize);
    datasize += bufsize;

    free(buffer);
}

FILE *f = fopen(..., "wb");
fwrite(data, datasize, 1, f);
fclose(f);

free(data);
```

Or simpler:

```
char *buffer;
int bufsize;

FILE *f = fopen(..., "wb");

for (loops = 100; loops > 0; loops--) {
    buffer = getBuffer(&bufsize);
    if (fwrite(buffer, bufsize, 1, f) != 1) {
        free(buffer);
        break;
    }
    free(buffer);
}

fclose(f);
```

However, you tagged your question as `C++`, even though you are not actually using C++ code.  The C++ way to handle this would look more like this instead:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void getBuffer(std::vector<char> &buffer)
{
    ...
    buffer.resize(...); // <-- number of bytes
    // fill buffer with bytes as needed...
}

...

std::string data;

for (loops = 100; loops > 0; loops--) {
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    getBuffer(buffer);
    data.append(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
}

std::ofstream f(..., std::ios_base::binary);
f.write(data.c_str(), data.size());
f.close();
```

Or simpler:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void appendBuffer(std::string &buffer)
{
    ...
    buffer.append(...); // <-- append bytes
}

...

std::string data;

for (loops = 100; loops > 0; loops--) {
    appendBuffer(data);
}

std::ofstream f(..., std::ios_base::binary);
f.write(data.c_str(), data.size());
f.close();
```

Or simpler:

```
#include <fstream>

bool outputBuffer(std::ostream &out)
{
    ...
    return out.write(...); // <-- write bytes
}

...

std::ofstream f(..., std::ios_base::binary);

for (loops = 100; loops > 0; loops--) {
    if (!outputBuffer(f)) break;
}

f.close();
```

Comment: I'm not really sure if we should answer that question beyond what was already said in comments. But have an upvote for _being nice_ ;-)